# xpath find node that does not contain child

Tags: xpath, html-parsing, xml-parsing

I'm trying to create some xpath that will find all `a` tags that do not contain `img` tags, so that something such as

```
<a href="http://aol.com">link</a>
```

matches, but

```
<a href="http://yahoo.com"><img src="http://yahoo.com/logo.png"></a>
```

does not.

Of course I could do this in a two-part search but I'm sure there must be some way to do this with xpath.

Answer (score 61):

```
//a[not(img)]
```

Try and avoid the `//` if you can, though. Also note this will only exclude `a`s that *directly* contain `img`s.

Comment: XPath expression for _"any `a` element not having an `img` descendant element"_: `//a[not(.//img)]`

Comment: I needed first td which did not have a link `//table/tr/td[1][not(a) and not(b)]`.  The html had used td for table headers, and the table headers were wrapped in `<b>`, so I had to skip those as well.