# Freemind map xml parsing get last childs with simplexml php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml, freemind

I am having an issue when parsing  with SimpleXML an XML file what actually freemind map.

XML example:

```
<map version="1.0.1">
<node TEXT="str_1">
    <node TEXT="str_2">
        <node TEXT="str_3"/>
        <node TEXT="str_4">
            <node TEXT="str_5">
                <node TEXT="str_6"/>
            </node>
            <node TEXT="$ str_7"/>
            <node TEXT="str_8"/>
            <node TEXT="$ str_9"/>
        </node>
    </node>
    <node TEXT="str_10"/>
    <node TEXT="str_11"/>
    <node TEXT="$ str_12"/>
</node>
</map>
```

And with folowing code i can get all childs:

```
function print_node_info($father, $node)
{

        $output_xml = $node['TEXT'].' - Son of - '.$father.'</br>';

        echo $output_xml;

            // $file = 'output.xml';
            // // Open the file to get existing content
            // $output_xml .= file_get_contents($file);
            // // Write the contents back to the file
            // file_put_contents($file, $output_xml);

                //echo 'father: ' . $father.'<br>';
                //echo 'node: ' . $node['TEXT'].'<br><br>';
                foreach ($node->children() as $childe_node)
                //foreach $xml->xpath("//node[last()]")[0]->attributes() as $Id)
                //foreach ($node as $childe_node) 
                {
                    $GLOBALS['grandfather'] = $father;
                    print_node_info($node['TEXT'], $childe_node);
                }   
}

$xml = simplexml_load_file('1.xml');

foreach ($xml->children() as $first_node) {
print_node_info("top_name", $first_node);
}
```

What i am trying to get is only all last children's TEXT value, actually nodes which not contains children's.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this rather easily using [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](https://php.net/manual/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) and [`array_map`](https://php.net/manual/function.array-map.php).

```
$values = array_map(function($node) {
    return (string) $node['TEXT'];
}, $xml->xpath('//node[not(node)]'));
```

You can see that first we get an array of [node that do not have children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5464272/142162), then we transform each of those nodes into a string containing the node's `TEXT` attribute.

Comment: Thank you Tim, with var_dump i can see it works, but not so easy for me, my php near basic level.