# XPath node that doesn't contain a child

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I'm trying to access a certain element from by using XML but I just can't seem to get it, and I don't understand quite why.

```
<ul class="test1" id="content">
                <li class="list">
                    <p>Insert random text here</p>
                        <div class="author">
                            </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list">
                    <p>I need this text here</p>
                </li>
    </ul>
```

Basically the text I want is the second one but I want/need to use something similar to p[not(div)] as to retrieve it.

I have tried the methods from the following link but to no avail ([xpath find node that does not contain child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464272/xpath-find-node-that-does-not-contain-child))

Here is how I tried accessing the text:

```
ul[contains(@id,"content")]//p[not(.//div)]/text()
```

If you have any possible answers, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML snippet posted in question shows that both `p` elements **do not contain** any `div`, so the expression `//p[not(.//div)]` would match both `p`. The first `p` element **is sibling of** the `div` (both shares the same parent element `li`) instead of parent or ancestor. The following XPath expression would match text nodes from the 2nd `p` and not those from the first one:

```
//ul[contains(@id,"content")]/li[not(div)]/p/text()
```

Brief explanation:

- `//ul[contains(@id,"content")]`: find `ul` elements where `id` attribute value contains text "content"
- `/li[not(div)]`: from such `ul` find child elements `li` that don't have child element `div`. This will match only the end `li` in the example HTML
- `/p/text()`: from such `li`, find child elements `p` and then return child text nodes form such `p`

Comment: Solved !

Thanks a lot